# Why can't I apply a single step of a function like I do with definition in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I'm trying to do:

```
datatype my_bool = true | false
value "true" (* it has value true with type my_bool *)

fun conj :: "my_bool ⇒ my_bool ⇒ my_bool" where 
"conj true true = true" |
"conj _ _ = false"

lemma "conj true true = true"
  apply (simp only: conj_def)
```

but I get error:

```
Undefined fact: "conj_def"⌂
```

I understand the error but not why I can't apply a single simp like I do with definitions. Is this possible with functions at all?

Answer (score 4):

When you define a new constant using the command `definition`, a theorem like `conj_def` is provided automatically (actually, it is possible to control the name of this theorem). The command `fun` does not provide a theorem `name_def` automatically (where `name` is the name of the constant). However, it provides a variety of other theorems. You can see such theorems by typing `print_theorems` after the specification of a constant using the command `fun`. For example,

```
datatype my_bool = true | false

fun conj :: "my_bool ⇒ my_bool ⇒ my_bool" 
  where 
  "conj true true = true" 
| "conj _ _ = false"

print_theorems
```

For example, in the code listing above the command `fun` provides the fact `conj.simps`, which is, most likely, what you were looking for:

```
lemma "conj true true = true"
  by (simp only: conj.simps)
```

---

Technically, it is possible to recover the original definitional axioms  in Isabelle/ML for any constant, including `conj` (some insight about the definitional principles can be gained from [1], but there could exist more specialized references for this):

```
theory Scratch
  imports Main
  keywords "get_da" :: diag
begin

ML‹

(*the implementation of axioms_of_ci and da_of_ci are based on elements of 
the code HOL/Types_To_Sets/unoverloading.ML*)
local

fun match_args (Ts, Us) =
  if Type.could_matches (Ts, Us)
  then 
    Option.map Envir.subst_type
      (
        SOME (Type.raw_matches (Ts, Us) Vartab.empty)
          handle Type.TYPE_MATCH => NONE
      )
  else NONE;

in

fun axioms_of_ci thy defs (c, T) =
  let
    val const_entry = Theory.const_dep thy (c, T);
    val Uss = Defs.specifications_of defs (fst const_entry);
  in
    Uss
    |> filter (fn spec => is_some (match_args (#lhs spec, snd const_entry)))
    |> map (fn Us => (#def Us, #description Us))
  end;

fun das_of_ci thy defs = axioms_of_ci thy defs
  #> map #1
  #> filter is_some
  #> map (the #> try (Thm.axiom thy))
  #> filter is_some
  #> map (the #> Drule.abs_def);

end;

fun apdupr f x = (x, f x);

fun axioms_of_const ctxt (c, T) =
  let 
    val thy = Proof_Context.theory_of ctxt
    val defs = Theory.defs_of thy
  in das_of_ci thy defs (c, T) end;

fun process_da t st =
  let 
    val ctxt = Toplevel.context_of st
    val const = t
      |> Proof_Context.read_term_pattern ctxt 
      |> dest_Const
    val _ = const
      |> axioms_of_const ctxt 
      |> map (Thm.string_of_thm ctxt)
      |> map writeln
  in () end;

val tts_find_sbts = Outer_Syntax.command
  \<^command_keyword>‹get_da›
  "print definitional axioms"
  (Parse.const >> (process_da #> Toplevel.keep));
›

datatype my_bool = true | false

fun conj :: "my_bool ⇒ my_bool ⇒ my_bool" 
  where 
  "conj true true = true" 
| "conj _ _ = false"

print_theorems

lemma "conj true true = true"
  by (simp only: conj.simps)

get_da conj_graph
get_da conj_sumC
get_da conj


text‹The type of the input to the command @{command get_da} is important:›

get_da ‹plus::nat⇒nat⇒nat›
get_da ‹plus::int⇒int⇒int›

end
```

However, as noted by Manuel Eberl in the comments, such axioms are not particularly useful for most practical purposes for the end users.

---

Isabelle version: Isabelle2020

---

References:

1. Haftmann F, Wenzel M. Local Theory Specifications in Isabelle/Isar. In: Berardi S, Damiani F, de’Liguoro U, editors. Types for Proofs and Programs. Heidelberg: Springer; 2009. p. 153–68.

Comment: Addition: The definition lemma produced for functions defined with the function package is fairly ugly, that's why it is hidden automatically so that users don't use it by accident and get confused. The `simps` equations are the canonical way to unfold the definition of a function defined by the function package.

Comment: I did `print_theorems ` after a lemma and it didn't display anything. When does it display stuff stuff? only after definitions? Seems to be a stateful command too...

Comment: @Pinocchio According to the documentation: "print_theorems prints theorems of the background theory resulting from the last command;..." Therefore, it should (at usually does) work with other commands. If you provide a reproducible example where it fails, I might be able to provide further assistance.